# What does "insteadly" mean?

Tags: meaning, vocabulary

I have seen it couple of times in a chat room on the internet. What does "insteadly" mean? Is it a shortcut of  "instead of"?

Comment: Could you provide a full sentence with it in? If you can also provide a link to the transcript of the chat where you saw, that would be perfect.

Comment: Most of the instances that come up on Google for me suggest that it is a mishearing/misspelling of "instantly." Maybe it is gaining traction as a neologism with a different meaning, though. I haven't seen it before today.

Comment: It means "I like to make up my own words and I don't care if people think I'm poorly educated".

Comment: Thanks all the people for the comments. May the God bless you.

Comment: @david- or I want to mix German and English together.

Comment: This reminds me of a wonderful word that appears on chat in my part of the world from mainly non-native-English speakers of Ojibway and Cree heritage -- "updation." I was fascinated to find the term on Wiktionary as one used in similar contexts in Indian English.

Comment: Updation is also a good one ;D.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not an English word. I don't think it's a mistake either, though. It's more likely to be a jocose usage.

Comment: You nailed it ;) Could we call it "playful cleverness" ;) ?

Comment: Sure...but what does it *mean*?

Comment: I think it was a chat about real-time search of alternatives on the internet and some guys came out with this word, which I believe is combination of two words: instant/ly and instead of ;)

Comment: Ah! So, we'd call this sort of usage a [portmanteau](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portmanteau).

Comment: @MarkBeadles Stop stealing French words ! :'(

Answer (score 1):

"Insteadly" is not a standard English word. As others have noted, it appears to be a typo for **instantly**.

I would think this is probably due the pronunciation of [ˈɪnstəntli] as [ˈɪnstədli] in quick speech, where the hearer has not seen the word spelled before.

---

EDITED TO ADD: After a Google perusal I see only three usages:

1. This post.
2. Non-native English speakers using it in place of "instantly".
3. Non-native English speaker using it in place of "instead".

Comment: Not everything is indexed on Google. Some chat rooms and websites are private, you need an access to a member area, which is impossible for Google bot too.

Comment: @Derfder. Yes, but while a Google search is not definitive, it certainly can help answer whether a word is in widely-accepted, or even narrowly-accepted, use or not. If the word is only used in chat rooms and private websites, then it is not likely to be considered an English word with a clear meaning.

In particular, your argument makes this question "too localized".

Comment: @Noah I didn't, it's still there. No big deal, I've had plenty of downvotes :) I was just curious as to why.

Answer (score -1):

Never heard of it. None of the dictionaries seem to have it listed under their belt. It could be a typo for *instantly* or simply *instead*.